# typescript: как показать map, что надо возвращать данные конкретного типа

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-типы, приведение-типов

есть интерфейс:

```
export interface IData {
    name    : string,
    place?  : number
}
```

требуется получить массив таких данных из массива других данных с помощью метода `map`

если делать так:

```
const data: IData[] = arr.map((elem: IElem) => ({
    name: elem.name,
    place: elem.place
}));
```

то будет ошибка:

```
Type '{ name: string; place: number | undefined; }[]' is not assignable to type 'IData[]'.
```

Как корректно от нее избавиться?

Comment: Очень странно. [Песочница typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQBFMZM4BvAKDhriUwFs9aAuOAZximQHMAaarTAAbHMAD8NNkgCuDAEZpKAX0qVQkWIhRosuAgFFhwBhUE16TNp25J+5uCLHS5iqHAA+cGUgAmwdGRgXwFaOAA3TGFrLl4VNWwIJE44TCgoNnwjEwBtAF04AF44HKowy2A2AHIAJhqq0KFRXDYARkaaSOi4KoAWfqqVPIBuBKSU3xJMTOJSfKLU9IA6BkwwAAp14GMGTOyGAEoigD44dbLaCrZtkyWKjsdmyrgbhiWnXBUDg9HKIA) не ругается

Comment: Так может ругаться есть `IData` не совпадает по типам с `IElem`

Comment: @SwaD, ну так надо с настройками немного [похимичить](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQBFMZM4BvAKDhriUwFs9aAuOAZximQHMAaarTAAbHMAD8NNkgCuDAEZoBAX0qVQkWIhRosuAgFFhwBhUE16TNp25J+5uCLHS5iqHAA+cGUgAmwdGRgXwFaOAA3TGFrLl5KVUpsCCROOEwoKDZ8IxMAbQBdOABeOFyqMMtgNgByACZa6tChUVw2AEYmmkjouGqAFgHq+PyAbjUklPhfEkws4lIC4rSMgDoGTDAACk3gYwYsnIYASmKAPjhN8tpKtl2TFcrOxxaquDuGFadceKOjscogA).

Comment: @Grundy, в сообщении об ошибке типы указаны.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я к тому, что может `IData` реальный отличался

Comment: @Grundy, вариант из ответа мне кажется более логичным, чем то, что в вопросе не тот интерфейс.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, выглядит логичнее.

Comment: да, `IData` и `IElem` отличаются, но по идее я из одного массива `IElem[]` создают другой массив `IData[]`, зачем требуется, чтоб типы были одинаковыми?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая ошибка может быть только при включенной опции `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` - отсутствие поля требует именно отсутствие, а не поле `undefined`, поэтому если указанный тип явно его не допускает, то нельзя.

Исправляется явным указанием `undefined` в типе: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQBFMZM4BvAKDhriUwFs9aAuOAZximQHMAaarTAAbHMAD8NNkgCuDAEZo4AHzgykAE2DpkwDQIC+lSqEixEKNFlwEAosOAMKgmvSZtO3JPxdwRY6TlFKBU1TW1dfV8AN0xhDy5eSiNKbAgkTjhMKCg2fHtHAG0AXTgAXjhCqlo6RmA2AHIAJiaGgRr-XDYARnbaWPi4BoAWUYbk4oBuYzSM+A0STDziUhLyrJyAOgZMMAAKPeAHBjyChgBKcoA+OD3q2jd6uCPHTce+mk6nl4ZNr+TzudppQgA)

```
export interface IData {
    name    : string,
    place?  : number | undefined,
}
```